# Nanogallery2's lightbox for single images on same site

Tags: javascript, html, nanogallery

I have a HTML-page with some different Nanogallery2-gallerys inside - works fine. 
Now I also have some paragraphs with single-images outside of the gallerys but on the same site.
How can I add **the same lightbox-effect** to theese single images without creating a gallery?
I'm missing some magic like adding a class like 'nano2gallery-lightbox' to use the same lightbox for single images.

Comment: EDIT: for a better understanding, my single-images are like this: 


`<a href='mywebsite.com/images/image.jpg'><img class='img_right' src='mywebsite.com/images/thumb_image.jpg' /></a>`

Comment: this feature has been implemented in nanogallery2 v3.0.0 - https://github.com/nanostudio-org/nanogallery2/releases/tag/v3.0.0